# How to test & parse brackets from a String?

Tags: java, string, parsing, brackets

On the Platform Discord, there are so called Embeds. They can be customized, and we want a command to send those.

We want the command to look like this: *!embed [This here goes as a title] [This here goes as a description] [And a argument for Color]*

Now, i would have to check whether the brackets are balanced or not, so i can be sure to continue reading what is between those.
How would you check and then get the Text between the brackets?

I thougt of something like this:

```
if(x % 2 == 0) { //Checking if x (number of opening and closing brackets) are equals (divisible by 2)
 //Continue with sending the Embed
}
```

Now the Question is after i check for balanced brackets, how i would get the text between them?
Any ideas?
I thought about something with checking every character and one char after the bracket i would start adding up the chars to a String until the closing bracket comes.

Other ideas or easier approches?

Comment: Use stacks data structure for checking paranthesis is balanced. Just push when ever you see a open braces and pop when you see a closed braces. At the end, is stack is empty its balanced otherwise its not.

Comment: `int openBrackets = inputString.replaceAll("[^\\[]", "").length(); int closeBrackets = inputString.replaceAll("[^\\]]", "").length(); if (openBrackets != closeBrackets) { System.err.println("The Square Brackets are not balanced"); return; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to extract the strings between brackets is to use **regex**.
For example:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)]");
    String x =  "!embed [This here goes as a title] [This here goes as a description] [And an argument for Color]";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Gives:

```
This here goes as a title
This here goes as a description
And an argument for Color
```

Comment: Solved it! Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

To check parenthesis you can use Stack, whenever you find an opening parenthesis you push it into the stack. and when you find closing parenthesis you pop from the Stack.
In the end, If the stack is empty then the parenthesis are balanced.